# Permission denied when editing files in /Library/WebServer/Documents

Tags: permission

I've added a webroot directory and file within /Library/WebServer/Documents. The web site/file displays fine but when I try edit it within PHPStorm or when using `nano` (without sudo) I get file permission issues.

The parent directory of the webroot is owned by `root:wheel` and has 777 permissions.

Within the web directory `mysite` the permissions and owners are as follows:

```
jcogan@/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite

drwxrwxrwx@ 15 root    wheel   480 11 May 10:25 .
drwxrwxrwx  11 root    wheel   352 22 May 13:17 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 jcogan  staff  6148  8 May 14:16 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx@ 43 jcogan  staff  1376 22 May 14:03 web
```

Then in /web

```
drwxrwxrwx@ 43 jcogan  staff        1376 22 May 14:03 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 15 root    wheel         480 11 May 10:25 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 jcogan  staff        6148 25 Apr 17:25 .DS_Store
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jcogan  staff          18 22 May 14:12 phpinfo.php
```

Are my owners configured wrong ?

Comment: Could you tell us what version of macOS you are running? How did you install `PHPStorm`?

Comment: Have you checked ACL's, try `ls -ale` to see if there are any.

Comment: PHPStorm was installed on trial basis. The issue was ACL.Had to change ACLs via Get Info on the directory. Thanks @sansSpoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked ACL's? Try ls -ale to see if there are any.